# Cython: Linked List of Extension Type

Tags: python, class, pointers, struct, cython

I need a linked list using Cython extension type ie. `cdef class` but the Cython compiler complains about Python object.

```
cdef class Item:
    cdef Item* prev
    cdef Item* next
```

Cython error: `Pointer base type cannot be a Python object`

It would be `cdef struct` but any work-around for using `cdef class`? (coz I need methods and OOP convention)

Comment: You could use a [C++ class](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#declare-class-with-cdef-cppclass). Note also that Cython wraps most of the C++ STL including `std::list<T>`, see [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/list.pxd). So it's not really needed to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cdef class` is like any other Python object and is stored/passed by reference.

This means that it isn't necessary to use pointers here: the internal representation is already stored with pointers. Therefore just use `cdef Item`.

As with any other Python object, your `Item` will be reference counted and will be automatically reallocated when no other reference exists to it.

Comment: @Dave when using `cdef Item prev,next` directly, i have problem because `prev` and `next` are created in __init__ and infinite recursion occurs

Comment: `cdef Item` really means "`Item or None`") so you can assign `None` to it to terminate the infinite recursion